# javascript appendChild did not work and give me an [obect] result

Tags: javascript, appendchild

Running the following code, I get the results like:

```
[object HTMLHeadingElement]
[object HTMLHeadingElement]
[object HTMLHeadingElement]
[object HTMLHeadingElement]
```

But it should have some result of some `ul` list. I do not know where I am going wrong. What am I missing?

```
function textContent(ele,value){
    var content = ele.textContent;//check if textContent is defined
    if(value === undefined){//no value passed, so return current text

        if(content !== undefined) return content;
        else return ele.innerText;

    }else{//a value is passed, so set text

        if(content !== undefined)  ele.textContent = value;
        else ele.innerText = value;

    }
}


(function(){
    var titles = document.querySelectorAll('.docHomeDetails h3');
    var sideList = document.getElementsByClassName('sideList')[0];
    var ul = document.querySelectorAll('.sideList ul')[0];


    window.onload = function(){
        for(var i = 0; i< titles.length; i++){

            var  li = document.createElement('li');

            textContent(li, titles[i]);//setting plain text into li element
            ul.appendChild(li);

        }                       
    }

}());
```

Comment: Where exactly are you logging that which logs `[object HTMLHeadingElement]`? What is your issue? Also, a `window.onload` is absolutely useless if you're going to wrap it inside another function... It is best used to wrap your entire code, although `addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', func)` is better imho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is here:

```
textContent(li, titles[i]);//setting plain text into li element
```

You try to assign an element itself not the text inside. Should be:

```
textContent(li, titles[i].innerHTML);
```

My [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ostgals/Lroxxyn2/).